# Regular expression for matching specific words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to match the beginning of specific words throughout a string. Say I have this:

> This is the example string of text.

I would be looking to match each T that starts a word:

> **T**his is **t**he example string of **t**ext.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with string.Contains( )?

Comment: In which program, application, or programming language are you trying to do this? There is some variation in commonly used regular expression engines.

Comment: @Alma Do I have tried a few things, but I'm not very good with regular expressions.

Comment: @CodeKwyjibo It's better if you could put those things you tried in your question.

Comment: @Jerry, I kind of forgot the different things I tried. I was trying a bunch of stuff, and then assumed I could find an answer on here, but wasn't able to, so I created an account and posted the question. I'll consider your advice for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying in irb (Ruby):

```
irb(main):001:0> "This is the example string of text.".scan(/\bt\w+/i)
=> ["This", "the", "text"]
```

for `/\bt\w+/i`, `\b` is the boundary, `t` is the character `t` that you want to start with, and `\w+` is alphanumeric or underscore, with 1 or more occurrences.  The `i` is ignore case.

If you want only alphabets and want to match just a `t` as well, then you can use

```
irb(main):002:0> "This is the example string of text.".scan(/\bt[a-z]*/i)
=> ["This", "the", "text"]
```

The `[a-z]` means the class of characters from `a` to `z`.  `*` means 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: I think this `/\bt[a-z]*/i` is exactly what I'm looking for. I'd also be looking to match any character within in the word, so would this be the correct fix for that `/\bt.*/i` ? I tested it some and it seems to be giving me what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `\b` metacharacter limits a regular expression to "word boundaries", meaning it will let you match "whole words only". By using `\b` at the beginning of your regular expression you can match whatever you want, as long as it starts a word.

In your example:
`\b[tT]`

Similarly, if you'd wish to match the letter **T** at the end of words you would just place the \b at the end of the regular expression.

Comment: Would that fail to match the `1` in `1/3`?

Comment: When I've tested it, the 1 in 1/3 matches just fine if you use \b[1]